# Rails 5 RC1 - POST attributes not available in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm sending a POST request to a Rails 5 RC1 api to create a new vote record. I can see from `request.raw_post` that the attributes are included in the POST request, but they do not make it into `params`. I've attempted to `permit` the attributes with no success.

```
# article_votes_controller.rb
def article_vote_params
    logger.debug "### hello from the params function"
    logger.debug request.raw_post
    params.permit(:user_id, :user_type, :article_id, :article_type)
    logger.debug params.inspect
    logger.debug params.to_unsafe_h
end
```

The above code gives the following output.

```
### hello from the params function
{"user_id":"1","user_type":"User","article_id":"99","article_type":"Article"}
<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"article_votes", "action"=>"create"} permitted: true>
{"controller"=>"article_votes", "action"=>"create"}
```

Why wouldn't attributes that are included in the request be included in `params`?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the `permit` method returns a new instance of params, so if you did

```
p = params.permit(:user_id, :user_type, :article_id, :article_type)
logger.debug p.inspect
```

You would see the correctly, whitelisted params.